# Joining tables in MySQL question (php)

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

**Situation:**

In my database I have a table called '**artists**' and '**tags**'.

Each artist has a set of tags, saved in a linking table '**artisttags**'.

Each unique tag is saved in a table called '**tags**'.

**Problem**

I would like to show all artists that have one (or more) tags in common with a given artist.

```
function getSimilarArtists($artist_id)
{
   $sql = "SELECT ...";
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
   while($artist = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
       $html .= "<li>".$artist['name']."</li>"    
   }
   print($html);
}
```

**Tables**

*artists*

```
id | name
```

*artisttags*

```
id | artist_id | tag_id
```

*tags*

```
id | tag_name
```

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those outer joins in Mitosz's reply are really going to hurt - and will return every artist - not just those with "one (or more) tags in common". Use Inner Joins instead

```
SELECT similar.name, count(*) as commontags
FROM artists current, 
  artisttags curtags,
  artisttags simtags,
  artists similar
WHERE current.id=curtags.artist_id
  AND curtags.tag_id=simtags.tag_id
  AND simtags.artist_id=similar.id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Of course, for a smarter indexing system you could apply scoring to each tag in the tags table (e.g. based on user votes or cardinality) and sort your results by SUM(tag.score).

Comment: I get this error: Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Comment: and where should I provide the 'given artist id'?

Comment: Add to the query GROUP BY similar.id, similar.name.  Also add AND current.id=$currentArtist (with appropriate security checks).

Comment: Thanks SorcyCat - that's right (slight brain fade on my part)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name FROM artisttags at
LEFT JOIN artisttags at2
ON at2.tag_id = at.tag_id
LEFT JOIN artists a
ON at2.artist_id = a.id
WHERE at.id = '$artist_id'
```

Comment: thanks! little mistake though: at.id = '$artist_id' should be at.artist_id = '$artist_id'

Comment: As symcbean said, inner joins would be more efficient, so you'd better use his answer ;)

Comment: Add line
GROUP BY similliar.name
after ORDER BY count(*) DESC

Comment: OK and where should I providen the 'given artist id' ?

Comment: Add to WHERE clause: AND current.artist_id = '$artist_id'